# Undefined behavior with setlocale and multithreading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c11, setlocale

[CppRef states](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale)<sup>2016-12-13 09:00 UTC</sup>:

> Because setlocale modifies global state which affects execution of
>   locale-dependent functions, it *is undefined behavior to call it from
>   one thread, while another thread is executing any* of the following
>   functions: `std::fprintf, std::isprint, std::iswdigit,
>   std::localeconv, std::tolower, std::fscanf, std::ispunct,
>   std::iswgraph, std::mblen, std::toupper, std::isalnum, std::isspace,
>   std::iswlower, std::mbstowcs, std::towlower, std::isalpha,
>   std::isupper, std::iswprint, std::mbtowc, std::towupper, std::isblank,
>   std::iswalnum, std::iswpunct, std::setlocale, std::wcscoll,
>   std::iscntrl, std::iswalpha, std::iswspace, std::strcoll, std::wcstod,
>   std::isdigit, std::iswblank, std::iswupper, std::strerror,
>   std::wcstombs, std::isgraph, std::iswcntrl, std::iswxdigit,
>   std::strtod, std::wcsxfrm, std::islower, std::iswctype,
>   std::isxdigit`.

This info seems ... surprising at least.

I know that it affects global state, *I'm fine with that* (otherwise I'd be using a different method to change locale).

I always assumed though (and I think VC++ at least implements it that way) that `setlocale` is thread safe vs. the functions that use locale.

Do the newer C++ standards (and `C`?) (that actually incorporate threading at all) say anything about this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The question that this links to is from 2010, so obviously it can't give an answer about C++11 or C11.

Comment: @JensGustedt - well the [3rd answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35583206/321013) is from Feb/2016 and does a pretty good job of highlighting the issues. Your answer here is still very much appreciated. I guess it's still a somewhat valid dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C11 the standard clearly states

> A call to the `setlocale` function may introduce a data race with other
>   calls to the `setlocale` function or with calls to functions that are
>   affected by the current locale. The implementation shall behave as if
>   no library function calls the setlocale function.

So, no, `setlocale` can not be supposed to be threadsafe, unless your platform makes additional guarantees.

Since this is a C library thing to which C++ usually just refers, my expectation would be that it is the same there.

In practical terms this means that you should only use `setlocale` in the startup of a multi-threaded program, before you launch any supplementary threads.